# Do any two ill-founded models of set theory with order isomorphic ordinals have isomorphic copies of L?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Let $M$ and $N$ be ill-founded models of set theory with $\textbf{ORD}^M$ order isomorphic to $\textbf{ORD}^N$.  Does it follow that $L^M$ is isomorphic to $L^N$?  If not, does isomorphism follow from a strengthening of the hypothesis?  Say, $(\textbf{ORD}^M, +, \times) \cong (\textbf{ORD}^N, +, \times)$?

More generally, does transfinite recursion between models of set theory with isomorphic ordinals always result in isomorphic class being defined?

Answer (score 9):

The answer to the initial question is negative: very little information is captured by the ordertype of the ordinals alone. One way to see this is to note that **any** two countable models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with nonstandard $\omega$ have order-isomorphic ordinals (this is a fun exercise: to start, show that their $\omega$s each have ordertype $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}\cdot\mathbb{Q}$).

This does not **at all** generalize to the case where we include addition and multiplication of ordinals, however.

Comment: So I'm trying to wrap my head around Shoenfield absoluteness in the context of non-standard models.  For well founded models, we have the corollary that our low level arithmetical sentences are absolute between well founded models with the same ordinals.  Can we add enough hypotheses to our ordinal isomorphism to get that the constructible universes in the two models are isomorphic, and hence have the nonstandard version of that corollary?

Comment: @HenryKlatt I'm not sure what additional structure needs to be put on the ordinals to "capture" the corresponding constructible universes. That's separate from the issue of making sense of Shoenfield for non-well-founded models, which can be done - e.g. "For every $\Sigma^1_2$ sentence $\theta$ we have $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash\theta\leftrightarrow\theta^{L_{\omega_1}}$." Since every model of $\mathsf{ZF}$, well-founded or not, has a thing it thinks is $L_{\omega_1}$, this applies generally.

Comment: And for that matter I'd separately argue in favor of ditching the ordinals for certain transitive sets anyways. Higher absoluteness results force us to do this: e.g. "For every $\Sigma^1_3$ sentence $\theta$ we have $\mathsf{ZF}$ + [large cardinal hypothesis] $\vdash\theta\leftrightarrow\theta^\tau$" for some appropriate definition $\tau$ of a particular complicated transitive set, which - contra $L_{\omega_1}$ - $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone **does not** prove exists.

Comment: In my opinion, Shoenfield absoluteness suggests an interesting relationship between arithmetic within a universe of set theory, and the properties of its ordinals.  I'm interested in studying computability within models of set theory to see what sort of set theoretic properties of the model follow from the internal computability.  I want to know what we need to "capture" the constructible universe so I know what sort of ordinal properties are on the table.  I'm currently in the process of writing statements of purpose for graduate school, so I'm trying to fill out my research interests a bit.